# Difference between setSupportActionBar and setActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

So I am trying to use a Toolbar as an ActionBar in an app. I am trying to use the `setSupportActionBar()` method in a fragment that is hosted by an activity that extends a class that extends `AppCompatActivity`. For some reason I'm not able to do `getActivity().setSupportActionBar()` at all, I can only do `getActivity().setActionBar()`. The problem with this is that `setSupportActionBar()` accepts an `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` where `setActionBar()` accepts only an  android.widget.Toolbar. This causes my app to be restricted to only devices using Lollipop.

A side issue I've found is that when trying to change the theme of my Toolbar to dark with

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: In terms of your original question, what the difference is, does anybody have any more insight into this? As I understand it, AppCompatActivity uses setSupportActionBar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getActivity()` has the class `Activity`, even if your `Activity` is a kind of the subclass `AppCompatActivity`. You have to cast `getActivity()`,  call

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar()
```

For the Theme-Problem you should post details where you have put what style-definition or rather put it in a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, the theme issue was solved by being able to use a android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar instead of android.widget.Toolbar.